# Cron schedule interval through plugin options?

Tags: filters, wp-cron

My plugin sets up a CRON job on plugin activation to run after every 5 minutes. I want to provide a section in my plugin settings page, where the user can specify an interval. How would I do it? I am using the `cron_schedules` filter to add a custom CRON schedule. I am thinking of using it to get the option value for the user set CRON interval. Is this the right way to do it? If not, then how should I do it?

Update:

```
//done in plugin activation
if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_custom_event' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'everyminute', 'my_custom_event' );
}

add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'add_cron_schedule' );
add_action( 'my_custom_event',  'cron_data_update' );

//This is where I get the value set from the plugin settings
function add_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $my_settings = get_option( 'my-settings' );
    $period = ( isset( $my_settings['my-cron-interval'] ) && $my_settings['my-cron-interval'] != '' ) ? $my_settings['my-cron-interval'] : 30;

    $schedules['everyminute'] = array(
        'interval' => MINUTE_IN_SECONDS * $period,
        'display' => __('My Schedule')
    );

    return $schedules;
}

function cron_data_update() {
    //do something
}
```

As you can see, I am getting the value set by the user via the plugin settings page. If nothing was set, I use 30 minutes as default. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: edit your post to show the code you have tried even if it doesn't work

Comment: Sure. It works actually, but I am not sure if that is the right way to do.

Comment: @mmm Done. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my opinion that's exactly the right way to extend the default schedule timings. I would be a little more informative with the display value but I think that is only example code.

**However**, one important thing should be taken into account. The default WordPress schedule implementation that is invoked as a side effect of http requests will be effecting your sites performance even more if you reduce the time intervals of schedule executions. So you should move schedule execution to cron jobs at latest at this point. You can read in detail about that here: https://medium.com/write-better-wordpress-code/optimized-use-of-schedules-c18c3c1383e9