# Add cron schedule to upload video on save_post

Tags: cron, videos

I made a custom plugin to get post data from another source, when I save a post, I get all data. and also upload a video from source server to our server.

But it take a while when saving post until uploading the video.

Now, When saving post I need to get all data from source, But schedule uploading video after 1 minute to upload it on background.

The Code Example:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_from_source');
function update_from_source($post_id)
    {
        // code for getting post data here
    function uploading_video()
        {
            // code for uploading video here
            // I dont need to run this when saving post
            // but add it as cron job for this post
        }
    }
```

How I can Add *uploading_video* Function to cron?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to only save a post meta value ( [or use a custom table][1]  ) which indicates that a video upload should happen. Also register a schedule that will query for all posts that are marked as "upload needed" and do the upload in the schedule execution.

https://gist.github.com/EdwardBock/85c971633ea1abf8f248f4fb468344ed

You can shorten the schedule timings ( [Cron schedule interval through plugin options?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203293/cron-schedule-interval-through-plugin-options/388248#388248) ) but make shure to separate your visitors requests from schedule execution by moving it to a real cron job.